# How to track location using GPS continuously using service in background

Tags: android

I am working on an app which will track user location and I have added proximity alert to do some action in that specific location. I practiced this using activity and it works fine, but in background it doesn't work.  Here is an example it doesn't work. Kindly tell me a solution if any one has:

```
 public class TrackLoc extends Service implements LocationListener{
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

@Override
@Deprecated
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
             LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
             10000,
             0, this);
     if (locationManager != null) {
        {location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
         onLocationChanged(location);
        }
}
```

Comment: visit Official Doc [Receiving Location Updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

Answer (score 0):

hope it will helps :

```
public class TrackLoc extends Service implements LocationListener{
LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
         LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
         10000,
         0, this);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
         LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
         10000,
         0, this);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Do work with new location. Implementation of this method will be covered later.
    Log.e("Location updated: ", "Lat: "+location.getLatitude()+" Long: "+location.getLongitude());
}
}
```

In this i replace request location code from OnStart() to onStartCommand() because of onStartCommand() is calls when another component, such as an activity, requests that the service be started, by calling startService(). Once this method executes, the service is started and can run in the background indefinitely. If you implement this, it is your responsibility to stop the service when its work is done, by calling stopSelf() or stopService().

Comment: Please add an explanation or comment the solution also, not just code

Answer (score 0):

If you need to track him just for proximity alerts use the [`Location API`s](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html), in particular the [`Geofence API`](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html).
You can track up to 100 `Geofence`s without burning the device's battery.